# iOS: Truncate a large string , and appending a suffix string

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uilabel

I need to display some text in two lines , e.g.

| a very large string string string |

| string string  ... - a suffix string |

The whole text contains two part

1. a large description string, need be truncated
2. "-a suffix string", won't be truncated

How to implement it in iOS ?

Comment: use truncate in middle, may be helps you,

Answer (score 0):

## **If you set it to NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddleit will truncate in the middle.**

You have to set the lineBreakMode. You can either do that from Interface Builder or programmatically as follows

```
  label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
```

## another Solution

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 21)];
NSString *string = @"The Dark Knight Rises at 7:45pm";
NSString *substring = @"at";
CGFloat pix = 120.0;
NSString *result = [self truncatedStringFrom:string toFit:label atPixel:120.0 atPhrase:@"at"];

label.text = result;
```

> My first idea would be two labels side-by-side both with fixed width,
>   but I'll assume you've ruled that out for some unstated reason.
>   Alternatively, compute the truncation manually, like this ...

```
- (NSString *)truncatedStringFrom:(NSString *)string toFit:(UILabel *)label
                          atPixel:(CGFloat)pixel atPhrase:(NSString *)substring {

    // truncate the part of string before substring until it fits pixel
    // width in label

    NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:substring];
    NSString *firstComponent = [components objectAtIndex:0];
    CGSize size = [firstComponent sizeWithFont:label.font];

    NSString *truncatedFirstComponent = firstComponent;

    while (size.width > pixel) {
        firstComponent = [firstComponent substringToIndex:[firstComponent length] - 1];
        truncatedFirstComponent = [firstComponent stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
        size = [truncatedFirstComponent sizeWithFont:label.font];
    }

    NSArray *newComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:truncatedFirstComponent, [components lastObject], nil];
    return [newComponents componentsJoinedByString:substring];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this and let me know..[image]